# How to do AB testing for WordPress on nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a large traffic WordPress site running on nginx which I want to do some AB testing for UX/thematic changes. Where is the best place to put the logic for this and ensure a 50/50 split of incoming traffic while monitoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/ab-testing) should be useful in your quest to A/B test. They include test config & monitoring. I've used Optimizely before with success.

Comment: Thanks Kale. Optimizely does look very convenient as a hosted option.